# Como saber se determinada coordenada está em um bounding box?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps-javascript-api

Tenho uma coordenada (lat e lon) e também um bounding box (minlon, minlat, maxlon, maxlat) e tenho que descobrir se um determinada coordenada está dentro da área. Até o momento não achei como faço, procurei nas documentações do Google Maps API e não achei nada referente.

Comment: Seu bounding box é um objeto do tipo `LatLngBounds`??

Answer (score 0):

Boas,

Não tenho a certeza se é isto que procura, mas já experimentou usar `.getBounds()` e `.contains()`?

Aqui está um um bom [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/rMy2B/)  que determina se uma determinada localização está dentro de um Raio de um marcador. Caso encontre uma das coordenadas especificadas no código, retorna "*True*".